# Problema con carousel

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo un problema con un **carousel** que cuando pasa a la siguiente **slider** se mueve hacia abajo un poco como si tuviera una linea más pero del segundo al tercer **slider** no se mueve. Ya intenté poner una linea en blanco a ver e igual se mueve y no se por que.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barrio|Monoton|Oregano|Sumana');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sedgwick+Ave+Display');
    
html body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-image: url("../images/fondo.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
}

#navbar {
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(204, 12, 12);
    color:white;
}
    #nav-a {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-size: larger;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        font-family: 'Barrio', cursive;
    }
    .fa-building-o:before {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.452);
    }

    #slogan {
        font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave Display', cursive;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 401px) {
            #slogan {
            display:none;    
        } }

#slider {
/* margin-top: 4rem; */
    width: 50%;

}    
    .carousel-inner {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        /* height: 24rem; */
    }
        #arrow-prev {
            -moz-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Firefox */
            -o-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Opera */
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Chrome y Safari */
            transform: scaleX(-1); /* w3org */
            filter: FlipH; /* Internet Explorer */
        }
        #nav-slider-arrow {
            background: none;

        }


a:hover {
    color:black;
    background-color:lightgray;
}   

#registro {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
    #registro-logo-card {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }

    #registro-card {
        width: 20rem;
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }

    .wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto -4em;
      }
footer {
    /* display: block; */
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(204, 12, 12);
    padding: 25px 0;
}
    .list-inline li {
        display:inline;
        padding-left:3px;
        padding-right:3px;
    }
        #foot-a  {
            text-decoration: none;
            color:white;
            padding: 1rem;
            border-radius: 1rem;
            font-family: 'Oregano', cursive;
        }
    .separador {
        color:gray;
    }

    #footer-copyright {
        color: rgb(83, 81, 81);
    }


  .scroll-to-top{
    text-decoration: none;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #555;
  }

  .scroll-to-top:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: rgb(214, 18, 18);
    background: none;
  }




 .home-row {
     font-size: larger;
     }
#home-slider {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.342);
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 2rem; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
        #home-slider {
        width: 95%;
        margin-bottom: 5rem; } }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        #home-slider {
        width: 50%; } }

    .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: -2rem;
        }
    .slide-item{
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    #text-slide{
        font-family: 'Sumana', serif;
    }
    #autoedif {
        font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Menú -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-fixed-top affix-top" id="navbar">
            <div class="row">
                <di class="col-2">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html"><i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </di>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <p id="slogan">un problema, una solución </br> ¡AutoEdifica!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-end navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#" id="nav-a">Contacto <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#registro"id="nav-a">REGISTRO</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <a href="#" class="scroll-to-top"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </br></br></br></br></br></br>
    <!-- Slider -->
    <div class="container" id="home-slider">
    <div class="row home-row">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="11500">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <p align="justify" id="text-slide"><span style="font-weight:bold">¡AutoEdifica!</span> Es la empresa que llegó a revolucionar
                                                                    la forma de trabajar, donde tu serás el mandante
                                                                    y tendrás todos los medios para continuar y
                                                                    mejorar una necesidad por medio de un par de clics
                                                                    podrás desarrolar tu proyecto en 3 líneas de
                                                                    trabajo, mano de obra, proveedor y despacho </br></br>
                                                                    Todo por un medio <span id="autoedif">"AUTOEDIFICA"</span></p>
                                                                    <p align="center">Soñar, Crear y Concretar.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                    <p align="justify" id="text-slide"><span style="font-weight:bold">AutoEdificador:</span> para registrarse y poder acceder a la 
                                                                    gamma de servicios y beneficios solo debes seguir unos 
                                                                    simples pasos que te guiará el sitio en donde podrás 
                                                                    registrarte llenando un formulario y listo.</br> </br>
                                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp; Podrás entrar a tu perfil en donde diseñarás y distribuirás 
                                                                    de forma fácil y sencilla optimizando tiempo y recurso 
                                                                    todo en un solo lugar <span id="autoedif">¡AUTOEDIFICA!</span></p></br>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                    <p align="justify" id="text-slide"><span style="font-weight:bold">SocioEdificador:</span> para registrarse y poder acceder 
                                                                    como prestador de servicios o proveedor solo debes de 
                                                                    seguir unos simples pasos que te guiará el sitio
                                                                    en donde podrás registrarte llenando un formulario 
                                                                    y listo.</br> </br>
                                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp; Podrás acceder a tu perfil en donde diseñarás y 
                                                                    distribuirás de forma fácil y sencilla optimizando 
                                                                    tiempo y recurso todo en un solo lugar <span id="autoedif">¡AUTOEDIFICA!</span></p></br>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- contenedor -->
    </br>
<div class="push"></div>
</div> <!-- Wrapper -->
<footer>
        <div class="fluid">
            <a id="foot-a" href="#">Términos y Condiciones</a>

            <span class="separador">| </span> <a id="foot-a" href="#">Política y Privacidad</a>

            <span class="separador">| </span> <a id="foot-a" href="#">RRSS</a>

            <span class="separador">| </span> <a id="foot-a" href="#">Preguntas Frecuentes</a>

        </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le agregué una clase al contenedor padre del slider `slide-cont` y le agregué en el CSS un `min-height: 250px` para que no pueda redimensionarse.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barrio|Monoton|Oregano|Sumana');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sedgwick+Ave+Display');
    
html body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-image: url("../images/fondo.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
}

#navbar {
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(204, 12, 12);
    color:white;
}
    #nav-a {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-size: larger;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        font-family: 'Barrio', cursive;
    }
    .fa-building-o:before {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.452);
    }

    #slogan {
        font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave Display', cursive;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 401px) {
            #slogan {
            display:none;    
        } }

#slider {
/* margin-top: 4rem; */
    width: 50%;

}    
    .carousel-inner {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        /* height: 24rem; */
    }
        #arrow-prev {
            -moz-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Firefox */
            -o-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Opera */
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /* Chrome y Safari */
            transform: scaleX(-1); /* w3org */
            filter: FlipH; /* Internet Explorer */
        }
        #nav-slider-arrow {
            background: none;

        }


a:hover {
    color:black;
    background-color:lightgray;
}   

#registro {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
    #registro-logo-card {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }

    #registro-card {
        width: 20rem;
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }

    .wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto -4em;
      }
footer {
    /* display: block; */
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(204, 12, 12);
    padding: 25px 0;
}
    .list-inline li {
        display:inline;
        padding-left:3px;
        padding-right:3px;
    }
        #foot-a  {
            text-decoration: none;
            color:white;
            padding: 1rem;
            border-radius: 1rem;
            font-family: 'Oregano', cursive;
        }
    .separador {
        color:gray;
    }

    #footer-copyright {
        color: rgb(83, 81, 81);
    }


  .scroll-to-top{
    text-decoration: none;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #555;
  }

  .scroll-to-top:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: rgb(214, 18, 18);
    background: none;
  }




 .home-row {
     font-size: larger;
     }
#home-slider {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.342);
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 2rem; }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
        #home-slider {
        width: 95%;
        margin-bottom: 5rem; } }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        #home-slider {
        width: 50%; } }

    .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: -2rem;
        }
    .slide-item{
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    #text-slide{
        font-family: 'Sumana', serif;
    }
    #autoedif {
        font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
    }
    
  .slide-cont{
    
    min-height: 250px;
  
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Menú -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-fixed-top affix-top" id="navbar">
            <div class="row">
                <di class="col-2">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html"><i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </di>
                <div class="col-10">
                    <p id="slogan">un problema, una solución </br> ¡AutoEdifica!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-end navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#" id="nav-a">Contacto <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#registro"id="nav-a">REGISTRO</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <a href="#" class="scroll-to-top"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </br></br></br></br></br></br>
    <!-- Slider -->
    <div class="container" id="home-slider">
    <div class="row home-row slide-cont">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="11500">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <p align="justify" id="text-slide"><span style="font-weight:bold">¡AutoEdifica!</span> Es la empresa que llegó a revolucionar
                                                                    la forma de trabajar, donde tu serás el mandante
                                                                    y tendrás todos los medios para continuar y
                                                                    mejorar una necesidad por medio de un par de clics
                                                                    podrás desarrolar tu proyecto en 3 líneas de
                                                                    trabajo, mano de obra, proveedor y despacho </br></br>
                                                                    Todo por un medio <span id="autoedif">"AUTOEDIFICA"</span></p>
                                                                    <p align="center">Soñar, Crear y Concretar.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                    <p align="justify" id="text-slide"><span style="font-weight:bold">AutoEdificador:</span> para registrarse y poder acceder a la 
                                                                    gamma de servicios y beneficios solo debes seguir unos 
                                                                    simples pasos que te guiará el sitio en donde podrás 
                                                                    registrarte llenando un formulario y listo.</br> </br>
                                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp; Podrás entrar a tu perfil en donde diseñarás y distribuirás 
                                                                    de forma fácil y sencilla optimizando tiempo y recurso 
                                                                    todo en un solo lugar <span id="autoedif">¡AUTOEDIFICA!</span></p></br>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                    <p align="justify" id="text-slide"><span style="font-weight:bold">SocioEdificador:</span> para registrarse y poder acceder 
                                                                    como prestador de servicios o proveedor solo debes de 
                                                                    seguir unos simples pasos que te guiará el sitio
                                                                    en donde podrás registrarte llenando un formulario 
                                                                    y listo.</br> </br>
                                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp; Podrás acceder a tu perfil en donde diseñarás y 
                                                                    distribuirás de forma fácil y sencilla optimizando 
                                                                    tiempo y recurso todo en un solo lugar <span id="autoedif">¡AUTOEDIFICA!</span></p></br>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- contenedor -->
    </br>
<div class="push"></div>
</div> <!-- Wrapper -->
<footer>
        <div class="fluid">
            <a id="foot-a" href="#">Términos y Condiciones</a>

            <span class="separador">| </span> <a id="foot-a" href="#">Política y Privacidad</a>

            <span class="separador">| </span> <a id="foot-a" href="#">RRSS</a>

            <span class="separador">| </span> <a id="foot-a" href="#">Preguntas Frecuentes</a>

        </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: muchas gracias! ah ya entendi basicamente era porque se estaba adaptando al texto y le debi poner un minimo de tamaño cierto? mmmmm ya se jjejejeje muchas gracias!

Comment: @Naoto exacto, como se te redimencionaba a menor tamaño simplemente le dices que no se permita bajar de ese tamaño y listo.